# Problem with integrating $2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r^3e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve the following the following integral:

$$2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r^3e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}dr$$

I know that the solution should be $4\pi$  but I keep getting $6\pi$ as a result.
I did the following:

$$2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r^3e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}dr = 2\pi \left(\left[r^3\cdot \left(-\dfrac{1}{r}\right)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right]_0^{\infty} -\int_0^{\infty}3r^2\left(-\dfrac{1}{r}\right)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} \right)$$
$$=2\pi \left(\left[r^3\cdot \left(-\dfrac{1}{r}\right)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right]_0^{\infty} -3 \int_0^{\infty}-r\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2} \right)$$
$$=2\pi \left(\left[-r^2\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right]_0^{\infty} -3 \left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right]_0^{\infty}\right)$$
$$=2\pi\left[\left(-r^2-3\right)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}\right]_0^{\infty}$$
$$=2\pi\left(0-(-3)\right)$$
$$= 6\pi$$

I would be grateful for any help!

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're misusing integration by parts. If we take $u=-r^2,\,v=e^{-\frac12r^2}$ so the original integrand is $uv^\prime$, your boundary term is fine, but $-u^\prime v=2re^{-\frac12r^2}$, so your $3r^2$ should be $2r^2$.

Comment: Yes thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake comes from mistaking the antiderivative of $e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}$.